# Is this use of struct pointers correct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct Grades {
int  grade1;
int  grade2;
int  grade3;
int  grade4;
int  grade5;
}
```

I created a pointer to a Grades struct using

```
struct Grades   *pointer;
```

and I have a function() that returns a (void *) pointer to a specific Grades struct.

How do I set my pointer to that specific struct using the (void *) pointer?

I was thinking:

```
pointer = &function();
```

but that gives me an error: "'&' requires l-value

Any ideas? And by the way, I can't modify the function so...

Comment: If the function already returns a pointer, just remove the `&`.

Comment: If this or any of your previous questions have been answered, please accept one of the answers. It will make people more willing to help you in the future. See how here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: You should start accepting answers that helped you or solved your problem. This is how you **[accept an answer](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If function() returns a pointer, you should be able to just do

```
pointer = function();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pointer = function();
```

If function() is returning a void pointer, you don't need to take the address of it, it's already a pointer pointing to a Grades struct.